# Highcharts Pie chart: how to hide the legend for all but the three highest values

Tags: highcharts

I have a pie chart that has 20 'slices' and I only need to display the Legend for the highest 3 numbers.

For example, my series:

```
        series: [{
        name: 'Costs',
        data: [
      [
        'Rent',
        2520
      ],
      [
        'Spending money',
        1572
      ],
      [
        'Travel',
        1325
      ],
      [
        'Home',
        1142
      ],
      [
        'Personal',
        949
      ],
      [
        'Groceries',
        577
      ],
      [
        'Car',
        469
      ],
      [
        'Clothing',
        415
      ],
      [
        'Gifts',
        391
      ],
      [
        'Entertainment',
        310
      ],
      [
        'Other',
        1480
      ]
    ]
  }],
```

Using the above data, I only want to show legends for Rent, Spending Money and Other.

I can see we have an *showInLegend: false* option but that relates to hiding series, where I want to hide legends relating to data *within* a series.

What's the next step?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to disable default legend and use your own, like in the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/N3KAC/1/

```
$legend = $('#customLegend');

    $.each(chart.series[0].data, function (j, data) {

        $legend.append('<div class="item"><div class="symbol" style="background-color:'+data.color+'"></div><div class="serieName" id="">' + data.name + '</div></div>');

    });

    $('#customLegend .item').click(function(){
        var inx = $(this).index(),
            point = chart.series[0].data[inx];

        if(point.visible)
            point.setVisible(false);
        else
            point.setVisible(true);
    });
```

Then you will have a chance to add condtions etc, which achieve your goal.